# Elegant way to ignore null when applying RANK

Tags: mdx

This article gives a method for ignoring null when applying `RANK` : http://www.bidn.com/blogs/CraigLove/ssas/2617/mdx-walkthrough

Is there a more elegant way of doing this than using `CASE` ?

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[City Rank] 
AS
    CASE
        WHEN 
            NOT ISEMPTY
            (
                (
                [Geography].[City].CurrentMember
                ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
                )
            )
        THEN
            RANK
                (
                [Geography].[City].CurrentMember
                ,[Geography].[City].AllMembers
                ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
                ) 
        ELSE
            NULL
    END     


SET [OrderedCity]
    AS 
            ORDER
            (
            [Geography].[City].AllMembers
            ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
            ,DESC
            )
SELECT 
    {
    [Measures].[City Rank] 
    ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
    } ON COLUMNS
    ,NON EMPTY [OrderedCity] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the `NonEmpty` function within `OrderedCity`:

```
WITH

SET [OrderedCity]
    AS 
            NonEmpty(
            ORDER
            (
            [Geography].[City].AllMembers
            ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
            ,DESC
            )
            )
    MEMBER [Measures].[City Rank] 
AS
            RANK
                (
                [Geography].[City].CurrentMember
                ,[OrderedCity]
                ) 

SELECT 
    {
    [Measures].[City Rank] 
    ,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
    } ON COLUMNS
    ,[OrderedCity]
     ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This way the `NON EMPTY` is applied on the set on the rows before it it put there, so there is no need to apply it on the rows themselves. Furthermore, re-using the set within the definition of `City Rank` allows Analysis Services to calculate the sorting only once, and cache the ordered set. Otherwise, the `Rank` would require the ordering to be re- calculated for each row.